LT3757 - Boost converter
I have 3 simple question regarding the LT3757 ic.

I don't know how many amps it gives from the gate pin ? The only information about the gate is given below. I need to know it so that I can select my mosfet which will be drived by the LT3757.

The table below mensiones that the maximum gate voltage provided by the LT3757 is INTVcc -0.05 . The maximum input voltage is 17.5 V for INTVcc. Does that mean if I connect it to 10 V, the gate will provide me 10V-0.05 =9.95V ?

There are some designs in which the INTVcc pin is not connected to anywhere, only connected to gnd via a capacitor ? how much volt and amp does it gives in this type of connection ?



Source: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt3757-3757a.pdf


You will find the suggested load capacitance Cg = 3300pF as Ciss in data sheets. This varies with the ext. FET RdsOn and Vgs as well as Si or SiC etc. Thus choose what does not exceed 3300 of if possible to match risetime. Otherwise risetime will change.

Can you estimate RdsOn now from RdsOn*Cg = Tr ?
Then understand Ig=Vdd/RdsOn?

Yes
see 1)


Sir thank you so much for your commects. Rds-on is between Drain and Source. how did you find Ig with the help of Rds-on @D.A.S.

Shouldn't be the correct formula Ig = (Ciss x Vgs) / Tr  @D.A.S.
​
​


You can calculate the peak sink and source drive currents from the numbers given. There's capacitive load (3n3), drive voltage, and rise & fall times info. The longer rise and fall times will lead to higher conduction losses, so you may want to keep the MOSFET's Ciss (input capacitance) close to 3n3. This doesn't necessarily mean you can't select a MOSFET with higher input capacitance. It depends on the operating frequency and target loss.
Yes. As long as the INTVCC voltage is kept within the limits, the peak voltage you'll get from the gate drive is 50 mV less than that.
The INTVCC pin is also the output of the internal regulator that produces a regulated 7.2 ± 0.2 VDC for the internal stuff. So you can connect a minimum of 4.7 μF capacitor to this pin and let the chip use the voltage. The output current is limited by internal dissipation (e.g. 95 mA for 15 VDC input, 40 mA for 40 VDC input), so depending on the MOSFET's gate capacitance, you may be allowed to use this output for external stuff, when needed.


Thank you sir for your comments. I have last question. I will use this to convert 3.3 V to 28 V. 1) I have some doubts about the gate pin will not provide sufficient gate voltage for the external mosfet  if I feed Vin with 3.3 V. 2) If it is not gonna work properly with 3.3 Volt, should I feed the INTVcc pin with 7.5 V or higher  ?  @Rohat Kılıç

@Mhan that information should've been included in the original question. For 3V3 operation, you are not allowed to apply an external voltage to the INTVCC pin. Read the datasheet thoroughly. It states that the external voltage to be applied to the INTVCC should be higher than 7.5V and lower than VIN i.e. 7.5 < INTVCC < VIN (VIN must be lower than 17.5V). Instead, you can use logic-level gate MOSFETs which can be driven with as low as 2.5 V.

I apologize for asking it here sir, it just come to my mind now. So basically if I feed Vin with 3.3, ic will not work properly right ? in this case I should tend to use logic gate mosfet as you said if ı decide to feed 3.3 volt ? @
Rohat Kılıç

@Mhan With 3.3V the IC can still work properly but the MOSFETs with a threshold voltage of, say, 4V shouldn't be used. For 3.3V operation you need to use a MOSFET with logic-level gate.


I don't know how many amps it gives from the gate pin

For a capacitor, \$i = C\frac{dv}{dt}\$.
The data sheet specifies that C is 3300 pF and that the output voltage is 80% of 7.5 volts (read note 5 in the data sheet).
Therefore, \$i\$ must be around 9.3 amps. You can also use this graph when you have different gate-source capacitance: -


Does that mean if I connect it to 10 V, the gate will provide me
10V-0.05 =9.95V ?

That will be about right.

There are some designs in which the INTVcc pin is not connected to
anywhere, only connected to gnd via a capacitor ? how much volt and
amp does it gives in this type of connection ?

If you are thinking of using that pin to power external circuits then it's best that you don't.
